# How to use environment variables in init container args in kubernetes/openshift?

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes, containers, openshift

This is an excerpt of my deployment config:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: GIT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: username
              name: git
        - name: GIT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: git
  initContainers:
    - args:
        - clone
        - '--single-branch'
        - '--'
        - 'https://$(GIT_USERNAME):$(GIT_PASSWORD)@someurl.com/something.git'
        - '/testing/'
      image: alpine/git
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: init-clone-repo
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /testing
          name: test-volume
  volumes:
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: test-volume
  ...
```

The initContainer fails, because *$(GIT_USERNAME)* and *$(GIT_PASSWORD)* are used as is and not expanded. I have tried *$GIT_USERNAME*, *${GIT_USERNAME}* and I am pretty much out of ideas.

How do I correctly use environment variables in args for init containers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add environment variable in the init container.

```
spec:
  initContainers:
    - args:
        - clone
        - '--single-branch'
        - '--'
        - 'https://$(GIT_USERNAME):$(GIT_PASSWORD)@someurl.com/something.git'
        - '/testing/'
      image: alpine/git
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: init-clone-repo
      env:
        - name: GIT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: username
              name: git
        - name: GIT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: git
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /testing
          name: test-volume
  volumes:
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: test-volume
```